# Destroy javascript validator in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation

Yes, exactly - destroy. Delete, remove whatever that eclipse would forget the syntax forever.

I went for every possible setting with immediate restart of ide - it refuses to skip the warnings and error messages. The worst thing that amongst trash messages I keep loosing the important ones.

Builders, Validation , JavaScript setting folders - I've been everywhere turned everything off both on project settings and general preferences. Tried even to turn off complete validation support. Reduced few hundreds errors to six yet again referring to .js files and yet again 1000s of warnings.

Can't really chill out and want really to identify with relevant words eclipse developers. It just shouldn't be like that. I went to relevant threads, the solutions don't work.

Version STS 2.9.2

**Is there any way to rip off the IDE from JS support?**

Comment: So far found only one solution: to remove project folder in javaScript include path tab so that "Source files and folders in the Global Scope" is empty. But I would rather remove support completely, so that I don't have to repeat this operation for every project.

Answer (score 0):

Open the **About** dialog, then click on the *Installation Details* button. There you'll see a list of installed features. I don't know how STS is packaged, but if you see a JavaScript feature you'll be able to select it and click the *Uninstall...* button. STS might package things so that JavaScript support is not installed as a separate feature, in which case you're out of luck.